# Android best way to call only a method in another class

Tags: java, android, object

I have a Class and I need to use it's method only once in another class. What will be the best way to call it? (Considering Memory management and performance)

> Assume I can not use static methods and these are the sample codes for question

```
public class UpdateApp {
    String text;

    public UpdateApp(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        //Some other works and initialization
    }

    public void update() {
        //Code for update somethings
    }

    //other methods
}
```

> Below code shows usage of only one method

```
public class MainClass {
    public void main() {
//        Method 1
        UpdateApp updateApp = new UpdateApp("path");
        updateApp.update();

//        Method 2
        new UpdateApp("path").update();

    }
}
```

1. What method is best for only executing one method ?
2. Will method 2 object destroyed after the execution of update method by GC?

Comment: What's wrong with the public method? Generally, you make something static if it does not change anywhere in the application, in that case, you don't need to create an object just to call a method. About the GC, as long as you don't pass anything a reference to something that is supposed to be normally GC, you are good to go.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad `you make something static if it does not change anywhere in the application` you might have mixed up final and static. static means that a method exists for the class and not for a specific object!

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are effectively the same (memory and performance wise). One advantage of method 1 is that it will be easier to debug issues if some exception happens, since it will be easier to know if exception happened during construction of UpdateApp or during update() method. Advantage of method 2 is less code ofc. There are probably some more delicate advantages, this is just of top of my mind.

And yes, in method 2 object will be destroyed by GC.